# Change the height of the div, at the bottom when hovering over it

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make my divs, on hover stay at their current location, but at the bottom, the one you are hovering on needs to gain an amount of height, how can i achieve this without using flexbox?
This currently happens: https://i.gyazo.com/746b8f3eb1ade6d870439ad4826adf9e.mp4

```
.p-block {
width: 100%;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
}

.project-block {
margin-left: 20px;
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
background-color: #000;
height: 300px;
}

.project-block:hover {
height: 380px;
}
```

and the html is as following

```
            <div class="p-block">
                <div class="project-block">
                </div>
                <div class="project-block">
                </div>
                <div class="project-block">
                </div>
                <div class="project-block">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Provide code otherwise it becomes difficult to help as we dont know how you have implemented it so far

Answer (score 0):

See if help:

```css
.p-block {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.project-block {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 300px;
}

.project-block:hover {
  height: 380px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-block">
  <div class="project-block">
  </div>
  <div class="project-block">
  </div>
  <div class="project-block">
  </div>
  <div class="project-block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100$;
}

.p-block {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.project-block {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 300px;
}

.project-block:hover {
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  background: black;
  height: 340px;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-block">
  <div class="project-block">
  </div>
  <div class="project-block">
  </div>
  <div class="project-block">
  </div>
  <div class="project-block">
  </div>
</div>
```